# Is there any specific reason for spring integration raise this INFO when processing the flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I created the flow below and it's working normally but all the time this information is printed in the log file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-5.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-5.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <task:executor id="taskExecutorRecursaoRendaVariavel" pool-size="15-20" queue-capacity="100"/>
    <task:executor id="taskExecutorProcessamentoRendaVariavel" pool-size="15-20" queue-capacity="100"/>
    <task:executor id="taskExecutorSplitterRendaVariavel" pool-size="15-20" queue-capacity="100"/>

    <int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-movimentacao-renda-variavel"/>
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="xxx-consolidador-splitter-recursao-renda-variavel" task-executor="taskExecutorSplitterRendaVariavel"/>
    <int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-channel-segrega-renda-variavel"/>
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="xxx-consolidador-splitter-renda-variavel-recursao-movimentacao" task-executor="taskExecutorRecursaoRendaVariavel"/>
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="xxx-consolidador-splitter-renda-variavel-processa-movimentacao" task-executor="taskExecutorProcessamentoRendaVariavel"/>
    <int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-direct-channel-movimentacao-renda-variavel"/>
    <int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-request-ativo-renda-variavel"/>
    <int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-request-movimentacao-renda-variavel"/>
    <int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-request-notifica-renda-variavel"/>
    <int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-filter-channel-renda-variavel"/>


    <int-http:outbound-gateway
            url="${xxxx.xxxxx.movimentacao-rendavariavel}?startDate={dtInitPosicao}&amp;endDate={dtenddate}&amp;page={page}&amp;recordPerPage=${RECORDS_PER_PAGE:250}&amp;cblc={cblc}&amp;cpfCnpj={cpf}"
            http-method="GET"
            expected-response-type="br.com.xxxxx.ciar.xxx.xxx.xxx.integration.response.ResponseRendaVariavelMovimentacao"
            request-channel="xxx-consolidador-movimentacao-renda-variavel"
            reply-channel="xxx-consolidador-splitter-recursao-renda-variavel"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, cpf, cblc, dtInitPosicao, dtenddate, page">
        <int-http:uri-variable name="cpf" expression="headers.cpf"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="cblc" expression="headers.cblc"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="dtInitPosicao" expression="headers.dtinitposicao"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="dtenddate" expression="headers.dtenddate"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="page" expression="headers.page"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <int:splitter input-channel="xxx-consolidador-splitter-recursao-renda-variavel"
                  output-channel="xxx-consolidador-channel-segrega-renda-variavel">
        <bean class="br.com.xxx.ciar.xxx.renda.variavel.integration.splitter.SplitterRecursaoRendaVariavel"/>
    </int:splitter>

    <int:header-value-router id="recursaoRendaVariavel" input-channel="xxx-consolidador-channel-segrega-renda-variavel"
                             header-name="recursao" resolution-required="false">
        <int:mapping value="true" channel="xxx-consolidador-splitter-renda-variavel-recursao-movimentacao"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:header-value-router id="processaRendaVariavel" input-channel="agora-consolidador-channel-segrega-renda-variavel"
                             header-name="processa" resolution-required="false">
        <int:mapping value="true" channel="xxxx-consolidador-splitter-renda-variavel-processa-movimentacao"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:header-filter input-channel="xxx-consolidador-splitter-renda-variavel-processa-movimentacao"
                       output-channel="xxx-consolidador-filter-channel-renda-variavel"
                       header-names="Authorization, authorization"/>

    <int:splitter input-channel="xxx-consolidador-filter-channel-renda-variavel"
                  output-channel="xxx-consolidador-direct-channel-movimentacao-renda-variavel">
        <bean class="br.com.xxx.ciar.xxxx.renda.variavel.integration.splitter.RendaVariavelMovimentacaoSplitter"/>
    </int:splitter>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="xxx-consolidador-direct-channel-movimentacao-renda-variavel" header-name="type" order="1">
        <int:mapping value="ativos" channel="xxx-consolidador-request-ativo-renda-variavel"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="xxx-consolidador-direct-channel-movimentacao-renda-variavel" header-name="type" order="2">
        <int:mapping value="posicao" channel="xxx-consolidador-request-movimentacao-renda-variavel"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="xxx-consolidador-direct-channel-movimentacao-renda-variavel" header-name="type" order="3">
        <int:mapping value="notifica" channel="xxx-consolidador-request-notifica-renda-variavel"/>
    </int:header-value-router>


    <int-http:outbound-channel-adapter
            http-method="POST"
            url="${xxxx.ativos}"
            channel="xxx-consolidador-request-ativo-renda-variavel"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, DESTINO_URL">
    </int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-http:outbound-channel-adapter
            http-method="POST"
            url="${xxxx.movimento-rendavariavel}"
            channel="xxx-consolidador-request-movimentacao-renda-variavel"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, DESTINO_URL">
    </int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-http:outbound-channel-adapter
            http-method="POST"
            url="${xxxx.notifica}"
            channel="xxx-consolidador-request-notifica-renda-variavel"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, DESTINO_URL">
    </int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>
</beans>
```

`2021-11-05 17:55:16,811 [taskExecutorSplitterRendaVariavel-1] INFO  o.s.i.d.UnicastingDispatcher - An exception was thrown by 'bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#6' for component 'recursaoRendaVariavel'; defined in: 'file []'; from source: ''int:header-value-router' with id='recursaoRendaVariavel''' while handling 'GenericMessage [payload=br.com.bradesco.ciar.agora.renda.variavel.integration.response.ResponseRendaVariavelMovimentacao@2a5ae9, headers={Transfer-Encoding=chunked, http_requestMethod=GET, sequenceNumber=1, processa=true, sequenceSize=2, dtenddate=20211105, Pragma=no-cache, http_statusCode=200 OK, Date=1636145712000, dtinitposicao=20211101, Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, cblc=161254, cpf=21333240899, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8083/renda-variavel/xxxxxxxxxx, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, timestamp=1636145716810}]': No channel resolved by router 'recursaoRendaVariavel' and no 'defaultOutputChannel' defined.. Failing over to the next subscriber.`

Answer (score 0):

Your `<int:channel id="xxx-consolidador-channel-segrega-renda-variavel"/>` is a `DirectChannel` with a `UnicastingDispatcher`, which has a logic to failover to the next subscriber, if the current one has failed. The logic is like this:

```
if (!isLast && this.failover) {
    logExceptionBeforeFailOver(ex, handler, message);
}
```

We log that message to inform you that this might not be an expected behavior. For example that was an accident to add another subscriber to this channel. The whole exception info is present there to let you know that your logic in the router has failed: you probably didn't expect that `No channel resolved by router 'recursaoRendaVariavel'` for your use-case.

From here, if you really think that your flow is doing OK failing over to the next subscriber for that router error, then you just can ignore such an INFO message in the logs or turn off INFO for `org.springframework.integration` at all.